# Dynamic query in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

Iam trying to get the total number of row of table using dynamic query but eventually iam fail to do so. here is my query:

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @result VARCHar(20);
declare @s varchar(10);
set @s='country';
SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@result +'=COUNT(*) FROM '+@s
EXEC (@sql);
select @result;
```

iam getting NULL value in @result.

Comment: you are not setting result variable so it is empty, also I am not sure what result you are expecting out of these SQL lines

Comment: So tell me how to set it

Comment: set @result='some thing'

Comment: also here no table is involved, you are just declaraing some variables, setting their value, and the Select query is also selecting one of variable

Comment: i did that in SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@result +'=COUNT(*) FROM '+@s

Comment: Table is country. and it work fine if write like this: 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+@s

Comment: the working statement has no equal sign before Count(*), and it is only dynamically placing table name on the place @s

it is not clear what do you want with @result in the query that is not working

Comment: that wat iam telling. it work fine when i remove @result.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this ...

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @COUNT INT;
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128);

SET @TableName = 'TableName';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @COUNT  = COUNT(*) FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@TableName)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
                     , N'@COUNT INT OUTPUT'
                     , @COUNT OUTPUT
SELECT @COUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @result VARCHAR(20)
declare @s varchar(10)
set @s='country'
SET @sql =  'SELECT @result = COUNT(*) FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@s)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@result varchar(20) OUTPUT',@result output
SELECT @result
```

Comment: constructive criticism:   you must always use `QUOTENAME()` function with your sql server object names, can save you against a possible sql injection attack.